# How to reduce the excerpt length from 55 to the value I want

Tags: php, wordpress

```
     <?php

     $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 2;

   $query_args1 = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'blog',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
     'offset'=>6,
     'paged' => $paged
     );

     $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args1 );
     ?>
    <?php
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
   <?php 
    if (has_post_thumbnail()){
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );   ?>
    <div class="hentry-post group">
    <div class="thumb-img"><img src="<?php echo $url;?>" width="65px">               </div>
     <div class="text">
     <h5><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></h5>
     <p><?php the_excerpt('20'); ?> </p>
      <!--<a class="read-more pull-right" href="#">→ Read More</a> </div>-->
  </div>
   </div>
```

And my functions .php code to reduce the length is .....

```
  function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
   return 20;
   }
   add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Can anyone tell me how to handle the content on will to show the least content as possible.....

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail. It is a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: It is a wordpress page that has posts, in sidebar I want to show some limited content from the post.........

Comment: You should include wordpress in your tags and add some details like that in your post.

Comment: updated is that ok...?????

Comment: got my answer....solution  is as follows......

Comment: Added following code in functions.php.........................................function excerpt($limit) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}    and wherever to use just add <?php echo $excerpt(What_length_you_want);?>

Answer (score 0):

Added following code in functions.php.........................................

```
      function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit); 
       if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) { 
      array_pop($excerpt);
      $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
       } else { 
      $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt); }   $excerpt = preg_replace('\[[^\]]*\]','',$excerpt); 
        return $excerpt; 
       } 
       and wherever to use just add 
       <?php echo $excerpt(What_length_you_want);?>
```